# Select from subselect

Tags: sql, oracle

So i have following sample query that results in an error (for those interested its : ORA-00904: "BLEH": invalid identifier)

```
select bleh from (
            SELECT MIN(mtb.id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY mtb.id) "bleh"
              FROM mytable mtb
             WHERE mtb.filtered_field_one = 0
               and mtb.filtered_field_two = 0
          GROUP BY mtb.foreighn_id, mtb.id
);
```

And if i change it into (note i replaced `bleh` with `*`):

```
select * from (
            SELECT MIN(mtb.id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY mtb.id) "bleh"
              FROM mytable mtb
             WHERE mtb.filtered_field_one = 0
               and mtb.filtered_field_two = 0
          GROUP BY mtb.foreighn_id, mtb.id
);
```

i receive result exactly as i would expect it from 1st query, and it looks like 1 column named bleh with proper values.

So why cant i select by the name (alias) of that column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you name a column with `"` double quotes, the database need that you call it as is, WITH DOUBLE QUOTES also! So try this way:

```
select "bleh" from (
        SELECT MIN(mtb.id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY mtb.id) "bleh"
          FROM mytable mtb
         WHERE mtb.filtered_field_one = 0
           and mtb.filtered_field_two = 0
      GROUP BY mtb.foreighn_id, mtb.id
);
```

Or this way:

```
select bleh from (
        SELECT MIN(mtb.id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY mtb.id) bleh
          FROM mytable mtb
         WHERE mtb.filtered_field_one = 0
           and mtb.filtered_field_two = 0
      GROUP BY mtb.foreighn_id, mtb.id
);
```

Even as I said `as is` I think that the comment provided by @Stawros is a valuable peace of information:

As for the column naming in oracle:

```
bleh = BLEH = Bleh
but 
"bleh" <> "BLEH" <> "Bleh"
```

Comment: and `bleh` = `BLEH` = `Bleh`, but `"bleh"` <> `"BLEH"` <> `"Bleh"`

Comment: @Stawros you are absolutely right! That is why I said `as is` :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos i actually knew that...dang...ok man, thank you :)

Comment: Glad that it could be of some help :)